# Tag deletion: "Multiple"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, burninate-request

The [multiple](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag is fairly useless...amassing 124 questions since its creation and with no real reason. Could this just be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it could but the community will have to do it.  If I recall correctly, the way for the community (including moderators) to delete a tag is to remove it from all questions. After that it will be automagically removed.

---

Get weaving.

Comment: Yep, we can merge 'em, but we can't delete 'em.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, exactly how it works.

Comment: Not many more than 100, so feasible. I've contributed my 10. As far as preventing its usage in the future goes, can tags be blocked?

Comment: I've done a bunch :: passes baton ::

Comment: The [tag:multiple] tag is no more!